# How to wait for an ElementHandle object click operation in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer, webautomation

I got a list of "list items" as ElementHandle array and now what I want to do is click on them separately (which will load some more data on the same page without navigating to another page) and then click on another button which is loaded after I click on a list item.

This is what I've achieved so far:

```
       // get list of all li's
       let handles = await page.$$('div.listMiddle > div > div > ul > li');
        for (let handle of handles) {
            // get content of that li's
            let text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, handle);
            // if they contains some specific string then click on them
            if (text.includes('something here')) {
                await handle.click();
                // this is where I am stucked at
            }
        }
```

So I marked the place where I stuck with a comment on the above code. After clicking on a list item, I want to wait for the data to be loaded and then click on the button which is newly loaded. This button will navigate to a new page, but I'm gonna do this for multiple times. This means I need to go back and click on another list item again and then click on button again then it will navigate to another page do something on that page and then come back...

It goes like this for all list items. But there is no `wait` method for this handle object which has `ElementHandle` type. So how can I do that? (By the way I am writing with typescript if that is matter but I guess not)

---

Edit: If the question is too complex, just answer this; after `await handle.click()`, how can I get response of this click as a page or element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ElementHandle`s are created inside an execution context. It means that if you navigate to another page, that execution context is destroyed therefore the `ElementHandle` will stop working.

So, a few tips. First, instead of looping through the handles array you could get first how many items you have and then navigate to that page click the first item, do your stuff, navigate back, click the second item and so on.

So the steps would be:
 * Go to the page.
 * Get the number of items.
 * Loop using a while (`while(currentIndex < count)`)
 * Call page.$$
 * Get the element using `currentIndex`
 * Click
 * waitForNavigation
 * Do stuff
 * Go back

Second, you can wait for the navigation to the new page on click.

```js
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    handle.click(),
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There should be an example about this scenario in the documentation page of Puppeteer. Because getting a list of items, clicking them and getting results are seems pretty generic thing.